# Addition of particular numbers in a file using awk or grep

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I am looking for something like this:

**FILE NAME : fruites.txt**

```
Apple a day keeps doctor away
but people dont like it............... 23 peoples found.

Banana_A.1 keeps u fit 
and its very tasty.................... 12 peoples found.

Banana_B.2 juices is very good to taste
and most people like them
as well as consumed the most.......... 15 peoples found.

Anar is difficult to eat
as well as its very costly............ 35 peoples found.

grapes are easy to eat
and people like it the most........... 10 peoples found.

fruites are very healthy and improves vitamins.

Apple : The apple tree is a deciduous tree in the rose family best known for its sweet, pomaceous    
fruit, the apple.

Banana_A.1: A banana is an edible fruit, botanically a berry, produced by several kinds of large  
herbaceous flowering plants in the genus Musa.

Banana_B.2: A banana is an fruit, botanically a kerry, produced by several kinds of large  
herbaceous flowering plants in the genus Musa.

Anar :  The pomegranate, botanical name Punica granatum, is a fruit-bearing deciduous shrub or  
small tree growing between 5 and 8 m tall.
```

I want the addition of all peoples found except banana

ANS : 68 ( 23+35+10 )

I am able to find the count separately, but unable to subtract them

I tried like this

grep -E ".found" fruites.txt | awk ' { sum+=$3 } END {print sum }'

ANS : 95 (68+27)

grep -E "Banana|.found" fruites.txt | grep -A1 "Banana" | grep -E ".found" |  awk ' { sum+=$3 } END {print sum }'

AND : 27 ( only bananas)

Can anyone please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '$1 != "Banana" {s+=$(NF-2)} END { print s}' RS= fruites.txt
```

The key here is the `RS=` assignment which makes awk treat each section of text delimited by blank lines as a separate record.  Note that you may prefer to write `RS="" fruites.txt` for clarity, but that is not necessary.  Be sure not to omit the space after the `=`, though, as the key is to have a blank string as the value of RS.

-- Edit --

Given the comments and the modified question, perhaps you want:

```
awk '! match($1,"Banana") && match($NF, "found") {
    s += $(NF-2)} END { print s }' RS= fruites.txt
```

Comment: I have updated the question. if there are some lines about banana in the below. NF is not working. Could you please help

Comment: Just change `$1 != Banana` to a more general comparison: `! match($1, "Banana")`

Comment: awk ' $1 == "Banana_A.1" {print $NF } RS= fruits.txt

ans is fit and not found. As Banana_A.1 and found. are in different lines. Could you please look into it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand your last comment.  The example you quote look at the record that matches `Banana_A.1` and then try to convert the string `Musa` to a number, which generates an error.  If you need $NF to be the string `found`, then check for that condition.

Comment: Hi William, One small doubt. Could you please help..
IF i have multiples directories that contain fruites.txt. Then i need to use loop. Could you please help in that. For example : if i have 200 directories and get output as 
"directory1---sum
 directory2----sum"

Comment: This belongs in a separate question.  It's just looping in a shell script.

Comment: Thanks William for replying. I have tried looping. But it is not working. I have created new question. Could you please look into the link below and please help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786502/addition-of-particular-numbers-for-all-files-in-a-directory-using-awk-or-grep

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below awk command.

```
$ awk -v RS="\n\n" '!/Banana/ && /peoples found\.$/{s+=$(NF-2)} END { print s}' file
68
```

The above awk command sets a blank line `\n\n` as the  Record seperator value and check for the non-existence of `Banana` string and the existence of `peoples found.` string at the last. If both conditions are satisfied, then only the sum of third column from the last would be calculated. So `s+=$(NF-2)` also written as `s = s + $(NF-2)` contains the sum. Printing the value of `s` at the last will give you the total sum.

Comment: Hi Avinash, One small doubt. Could you please help.. IF i have multiples directories that contain fruites.txt. Then i need to use loop. Could you please help in that. For example : if i have 200 directories and get output as "directory1---sum directory2----sum"